# How to get rid of "server did not register with DCOM" errors in the log?

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-viewer

I have constantly firing the following error in EventViewer:

> The server {784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D} did not register
>   with DCOM within the required timeout.

How to get rid of it?

**UPDATE**

I see the following key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` and it has 2 values:

[image]

and `{653C5148-4DCE-4905-9CFD-1B23662D3D9E}` can be found under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID` and has following keys:

[image]

Comment: We had this same issue with Guid `{73E709EA-5D93-4B2E-BBB0-99B7938DA9E4}` (`microsoft wmi provider subsystem host`).  Solution for that's documented here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/026d9bd5-35db-45fe-ae08-9d9b06c37f83/hyperv-vm-goes-nonresponsive?forum=winserverhyperv  Hopefully that will help others hitting this through Google.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest you first determine which DCOM (Distributed Component Object Model) Server software is failing to register itself within a reasonable period of time.  To do this, you should run regedit, and search for  784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D

Hopefully, you will find this key under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT hive.  If you are able to find it, look at the "InProcServer32" and "ProgID" subkeys, as this will tell you what software is "timing out".   If its not under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, you may find clues to its identity under the other hives (HKLM and HKCU).

To make a long story short, some software is trying to register itself as a "Server" that other programs/machines can call remotely, and it is taking too long to set itself up during this registration process.

Once you determine what software is causing this, you should try re-installing, repairing, or re-configuring the software to see if that helps.  Also, once you know the name of the software, you can look in Event Viewer->Windows Logs->Application to see if that application is giving any errors.  Then, do a Google search on this error message to find the problem.

Comment: {784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D} is AUSessionConnectTaskHandler Class 1.0, and not some 3rd-party software. It's apparently related to Windows Update and how its design has changed over the years and versions. Appears that it should be disabled at Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > Windows Update > AUSessionConnect